# Calculate Wronksian of Second Order Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Use variation of parameters to find a particular solution to:

$\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{x}} + 2 \frac{dy}{dx} + y = \frac{1}{x^{4}e^{4}}.$

There are no solutions given so finding a wronskian that way is nil.
But since it is still in the order $p(x)y'' + q(x)y' + r(x)y = g(x)$ I think there is still a way to calculate a Wronskian. I have not worked with second order differential equations before and some hints/tips/help would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean the wronskian of the basis solutions of the differential equation $y'' + 2y' + y = 0$?

Comment: Maybe you can start to work on the homogeneous differential equation? Do you have tools to solve that?

Comment: @Chou Possibly. That is the exact prompt. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @mickep Do you mean finding the homogeneous solutions?

Comment: Xiao, I mean the differential equation where you replace your right-hand side $1/(x^4e^4)$ by zero. That equation is usually called the homogeneous equation. I think one should avoid to call the solutions to that one the "homogeneous solutions", since there is no reason they should be homogeneous (in the mathematical sense).

Answer (score 1):

you can see that the homogeneous equation $$y'' + 2y' + y = 0 $$ has the fundamental solutions $$\left\{  e^{-x}, xe^{-x} \right\}.$$ the wronskian $w$ is $$w = e^{-x} (xe^{-x})'-xe^{-x}(e^{-x})'=e^{-2x}\left( -x+1+x\right) = e^{-2x} $$  so that the wronskian satisfies $$w' = -2w $$

wronskian of $$ay'' + by' + cy = 0 $$ satisfies the abel's equation $$ aw' + b w = 0$$

Comment: Are the fundamental solutions just... there? I do not see how they are achieved.

Comment: do you mean you don't see how i got $e^{-x}$ and $xe^{-x}$ as solutions of $y'' + 2y' + y = 0?$

Comment: yes. I know you can get solutions by $\Lambda^{2}e^{\Lambda x}+ 2 \Lambda e^{\Lambda x} +  e^{\Lambda x}$ which yields $\Lambda ^{2} + 2\Lambda + 1 = 0$ factoring to ${\Lambda +1}{\Lambda +1} = 0$ where $\Lambda = 1,1$. Thus solutions would be $y_{1} = e^x$, no?

Comment: @Xiao,  the second independent solution in the case repeating root $\lambda$ is $xe^{\lambda x}$

Comment: Can you see where I am missing the negative sign in $\lambda$ ? I only see the roots at positive 1... nevermind... silly mistake.

Comment: Figured it out. Silly algebra kicking my butt again.

Comment: @Xiao, all of us make mistakes like that.

Answer (score 0):

Since the discriminant of the differential equation $y'' + 2y' + y = 0$ is $2^{2} - 4 = 0,$ it follows that $$u_{1} := e^{-x},\ u_{2} := xe^{-x}$$ are the basis solutions. If $x \mapsto w$ is the Wronskain of $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$, then 
$$w = u_{1}u_{2}' - u_{2}u_{1}' = e^{-2x}.$$

Let $R(x) := 1/x^{4}e^{4},$ let $t_{1} := -D^{-1}u_{2}R(x)/w,$ and let $t_{2} := D^{-1}u_{1}R(x)/w,$ where $D^{-1}$ means the primitive "operator". Then
$$t_{1} = -D^{-1}x^{-3}e^{x-4},\ t_{2} = D^{-1}x^{-4}e^{x-4}.$$ Then the particular solution $y_{1}$ is simply
$$y_{1} = t_{1}u_{1} + t_{2}u_{2}.$$

As to the underlying theorems, please simply check any book on ordinary differential equations.